# When are formula fields evaluated?

Tags: apex

This is a very simple question to which I have not yet found a good answer.

- The [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) does not mention formula field recalculation.
- We can recalculate formulas using [Apex - Formula Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm).

Scenario No. 1: We view an Account record using the Lightning UI. Formula fields on the Account display up-to-date values.

1. Is it because these values were present from the last DML operation on the record?
2. Is it because when we view a record in the Lightning UI, the system performs a SOQL query for the record values (does it really perform a SOQL query?), and these formulas fields are recalculated on SOQL query execution?

Scenario No. 2: We perform a record update through the Lightning UI (e.g. change the name of an Account record), which fires our after update trigger on Account, which performs update on all Contact records associated with the Account, and so the formula fields on Contacts should show different data.

1. During the order of execution, is there a particular moment when the formula fields on Contact get recalculated?
2. Can we use the updated values in our before triggers on Contact?
3. Can we use them in after triggers?

Also is there any official documentation that answers this question, because I have not found any more relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

No storage is allocated to the results of formula evaluations. They are performed on demand every time the database is queried. There's no mention of them in the order of operations, because it's not a specific step where the calculation happens as far as DML in concerned. In an after trigger, Trigger.old will contain the old formula values, Trigger.new will contain the new, recalculated values. That happens in the step where "the record is reloaded from the database" right after the temporary save that occurs after "before save" logic is done.

Comment: `ballots` ? did you mean `values`?

Comment: @cropredy Haha, yeah, I was mobile. Edited.